# como eliminar una fila en TableView y los datos de core data - swift

Tags: swift

estoy haciendo una app que guarda información en CoreData y la muestra al usuario en una TableView . Quisiera borrar las filas y los datos , creo que se puede implementar en esta seccion ?

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,  forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       if editingStyle == .delete {
           // Delete the row from the data source
           tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
       } else if editingStyle == .insert {
           // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
       }    
   }
   */

   /*
```

Implemente este codigos se borra las filas pero los datos regresan despues de refrescar la app

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if editingStyle == .delete {

     objetos.remove(at: indexPath.item)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar este codigo dentro del `editingStyle`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        switch editingStyle {
        case .delete:
            // remueve el item eliminado del modelo
            let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let managedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let context = managedObjectContext
            context.delete(tuArray[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            tuArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch _ {
            }

            // remueve el item eliminado del UITableView
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) default:
            return

        }

    }
```